# Creating a search function

Tags: python, binary-search

> Write an efficient function in the Python language called SmartSearch. This function will receive a sorted `arr` array of integers of size \$n\$ containing at the beginning \$m\$ "significant numbers" and the rest of the numbers are "fictitious numbers" whose value is 9999. The function also receives a number \$x\$ to be searched for in the array. If the number is in the array, the function must return its index (position). If the number \$x\$ does not exist, it must return -1. Important note: the size \$m\$ is unknown. Required efficiency: \$O(\log m)\$

I tried that, but I don't think it quite answers the question. I would appreciate corrections please. I realized that I should first find in which index the fictitious numbers start, and then refer only to the list without the fictitious numbers. How do you do that?

```py
def smartSearch(arr, x):
    if x == 9999:
        return -1

    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (high + low) // 2

        if arr[mid] == x:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1

    return -1
```

Comment: Yes, a programming challenge my lecturer gave me

Comment: The program works, just not exactly according to the requirements of the challenge

Comment: You *could* have an initial loop performed after you have initialized `high` as follows: `while high >= 0 and arr[high] == 999: high -= 1`. But what if you had an array of 200 elements of which the last 100 have the value `9999`. You would be looping 100 times to set `high` from its initial value of 199 to 99. If you did nothing you would compute `mid` initially to be 99. If `arr[99]` is less than the `x` value you seek you will discover on your next iteration that the value does not exist. Otherwise you have eliminated the 100 fictitious numbers with one search. So do nothing.

Comment: You are not sorting anything so why is this title "Creating a sort function" instead of "Creating a search function".

Comment: There is an ambiguity here. There is no condition that directly states that "significant numbers" have to be lower than 9999. What if: `smartSearch([1,88888,88889,9999,9999], 88888):`

Comment: The list is sorted

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the issues in the problem statement itself:

- Don't name a function `SmartSearch`; use `smart_search` due to PEP8.
- It's not helpful to define \$n\$ but then never meaningfully use it. It's implied that either \$m < n\$ or \$m \le n\$, but which is it?
- The word *array* is almost certainly mis-used. There are [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array) in Python but this is almost certainly not what the problem statement actually meant; instead it meant a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence).
- It's a bad idea to return -1 on failure for a function that also returns integers on success. This is a C-ism and not how Python is supposed to work. A well-designed Python API would instead throw an exception, possibly an `IndexError` or `ValueError`. Otherwise, a naive caller may try to use -1 as an index: which would index to the last element of the sequence and silently produce nonsensical behaviour!

For your purposes let's change the definition to accommodate all but the last point.

As to your implementation,

- You violated the spec by writing `smartSearch`, which (by the original spec) would be called `SmartSearch`, but shouldn't be *either*; it should be `smart_search`.
- Don't re-implement a binary search when [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) is part of the standard library.
- Write unit tests.

An implementation can look like

```py
from bisect import bisect_left
from typing import Sequence

FICTIONAL = 9999
NOT_FOUND = -1


def smart_search(arr: Sequence[int], x: int) -> int:
    if x == FICTIONAL:
        return NOT_FOUND
    idx = bisect_left(a=arr, x=x)
    if idx >= len(arr) or arr[idx] != x:
        return NOT_FOUND
    return idx


def test() -> None:
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3), 0) == NOT_FOUND
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3), 1) == 0
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3), 2) == 1
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3), 3) == 2
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3), 4) == NOT_FOUND

    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3, FICTIONAL), 0) == NOT_FOUND
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3, FICTIONAL), 1) == 0
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3, FICTIONAL), 2) == 1
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3, FICTIONAL), 3) == 2
    assert smart_search((1, 2, 3, FICTIONAL), 4) == NOT_FOUND

    assert smart_search((1, 2, 4), 3) == -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 1):

## lint

```
def smartSearch(arr, x):
```

Pylint reports:

> C0103: Function name "smartSearch" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)

Please have your lecturer recite these words
out loud before the class:

> [Pep-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) asks that you give functions `snake_case` names.

## magic number

Let us define

```
SENTINEL = 9999
```

## algorithm

```
    high = len(arr) - 1
```

This is just Wrong.
It clearly leads to \$O(\log n)\$ cost,
given that you assigned \$n\$ to it.

### determine m

Write a `find_m(arr)` helper.
It must complete within \$O(\log m)\$ time,
but that's easily accomplished.

To return a useful *estimate* of \$m\$,
start with `estimate = 1`.
Keep doubling the estimate until
you see `arr[estimate] == SENTINEL`
or it runs off the end of the array,
whichever happens first.
`Return` the estimate; it may be an over-estimate, which is fine.
It will be within an octave of the true value.

If for some reason you really want to be picky and
find the exact value of \$m\$,
that is still feasible within the time limit,
given integer inputs.
Just do binary search, between `0` and `estimate`,
for the value `SENTINEL - 1`.
Do **not** try searching for that value
between `estimate` and `len(arr) - 1`,
as that would be prohibitively expensive,
with \$O(\log n)\$ cost.

### determine the index

```
    high = find_m(arr)
```

Now you're ready to search in the usual way.

### large target value

It appears that `x > SENTINEL` corresponds to invalid input,
for which we could immediately return `-1`.

That is, the problem speaks of

> a sorted array of integers of size  containing at the beginning  "significant numbers"

The combination of "sorted" and "beginning"
implies that significant numbers shall always
be less than the sentinel value.

## test suite

When you write
[unit tests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase),
be sure to include cases corresponding to

- `m == 0`
- `m == n`

Comment: Since \$m\$ is unknown, but \$m \le \$n, then determining (or even estimating) \$m\$ is an \$O(\log n)\$ operation, so \$O(\log n + \log m) = O(2 * \log n) = O(\log n)\$.  Your "_prohibitively expensive, with \$O(\log n)\$ cost_" is wrong and misleading; perhaps you meant "_do not try a **linear** search_ ...".

Comment: Another variation: while doubling the estimation of  \$m\$, test for the overrun and for the sentinel value, and _also_ for a 'significant value' greater than the sought one. In the third case a binary search may use a comparator without a check for sentinel values.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, no, that does not follow. There are two cases, the first being \$m \ll n\$, in which the proposed algorithm definitely finds an estimate with \$O(\log m)\$ cost, independent of \$n\$, thanks to the great many sentinels. In the other case we have a much bigger budget, so the fact that we examined much of `arr` is irrelevant, given that the large \$m\$ value grants us permission to do that. // No, I didn't mean a linear search. I meant that we should not try binary search on the wrong half, on the high half, since that is bounded by \$n\$ rather than by \$m\$.

Comment: @J_H Yes, you are correct.  I failed to notice your telescoping `estimate` is actually \$O(\log m)\$, and thus much more efficient when \$m \ll n\$.

Comment: @CiaPan, when teaching a student, I prefer to keep things as simple as feasible. Often that corresponds to relying on composition of functions, so each one can be tested and reasoned about in isolation. There are certainly ways to implement a function that has several responsibilities and have the Right Thing happen in the end, but sticking to Single Responsibility is easier for fallible humans to get right.

Comment: Well, possibly my description was a bit vague, but nothing prevents us from writing the algorithm in single-responsibility functions. Just give the end-seeker the required value and make it return the index of the first greater or equal 'significant value' found, the sentinel found or the array's last item. Then the caller tests whether the returned item is a sentinel and choses a comparator which does or does not consider sentinels.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, could you show me the complete code based on my code? thank you very much

Comment: can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

## 0-based

Python is a 0-based language.  A sequence of length n has elements running from index 0 to n-1.  There is no need to write `high = len(arr) - 1` and then test using `<=` to include the end of the range.  Simply drop the `- 1` (and the cost of the unnecessary subtraction calculation) and test with `<`.

```
    low = 0
    high = len(arr)               # no "- 1" here

    while low < high:             # use "<" here
        mid = (high + low) // 2

        if arr[mid] == x:
            return mid
        elif arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid            # no "- 1" here
```

## Repeated indexing

You fetch `arr[mid]` twice in your search loop.  Indexing into a random-access array shouldn't be expensive, but why pay any extra cost?  Cache the looked up value.

```
        val = arr[mid]
        if val == x:
            return mid
        elif val < x:
        ...
```

## Reworked code

Using some of the suggestions by J_H and Reinderien, (although we still reinvent-the-wheel, since the requirement is to write the search function) we can rework the code as follows:

```
FICTIONAL = 9_999
NOT_FOUND = -1

def smart_search(arr: list[int], x: int) -> int:
    """
    Find 'x' in sorted list of integers, in O(log m) time.
    'arr' contains a 'm' actual values, and 'n-m' padding values.

    Returns:
       if present: index of 'x'
       otherwise: NOT_FOUND (-1)
    """

    # Fast fail
    if x >= FICTIONAL:
        return NOT_FOUND

    n = len(arr)
    if n == 0:
        return NOT_FOUND

    # Telescoping estimate of 'm'
    m_est = 1
    while m_est < n and arr[m_est] != FICTIONAL:
        m_est *= 2
    m_est = min(m_est, n)

    # Standard binary search
    low = 0
    high = m_est

    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2

        val = arr[mid]     
        if val == x:
            return mid
        elif val < x:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid
        
    return NOT_FOUND
```

## Testing

Let's mock an array with the sequence 0, 10, 20, ...
and count the number of times we index into the array.

```
class MockArray:
    """
    A mock array of length 'n'.
    The 'array' contains 'm' ascending values, followed by 'n-m'
    fictitious values representing unused entries.

    Accesses to the array are counted, for instrumentation.

    'm' is not returned by any public method.
    """

    def __init__(self, n: int, m: int):
        self._n = n
        self._m = m
        self._gets = 0

        if not (0 <= m <= n):
            raise ValueError("Invalid n and/or m")

        if m >= 1000:
            raise ValueError("m is too big")

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self._n

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> int:
        if index < 0:
            index += self._n
        if index < 0 or index >= self._n:
            raise IndexError()

        self._gets += 1
        
        if index < self._m:
            return index * 10   # Fake storage of ascending data
        else:
            return FICTIONAL    # Fake storage of fictional data

    def num_gets(self):
        return self._gets
```

Then we can add a small test scaffold ...

```
def _test_smart_search(n: int, m: int, x: int, expected: int, limit: int):
    
    arr = MockArray(n, m)
    index = smart_search(arr, x)

    assert index == expected, f"{m=}: expected {expected}, got {index}"
    assert arr.num_gets() <= limit, f"{arr.num_gets()} > {limit}"
```

... which creates the mock array, searches for the given element, and validates if the correct result was returned and no more than the given number of array lookups were made, to validate the time O-requirement.

Finally, we can use this to run a number of tests on a ***billion*** element array.

```
def test_smart_search():
    
    for m in range(1000):
        limit = m.bit_length() * 2 + 2
        target = 50
        expected = target // 10 if m*10 > target else NOT_FOUND
        
        _test_smart_search(1_000_000_000, m, target, expected, limit)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_smart_search()
```